# H2 Embedded db need to change permission of database file h2db.mv.db through java

Tags: java, h2db

Can we change the permission of **h2db.mv.db** file. Right now it is set to 664 need to change to 770 through java code.

Answer (score 0):

To change permissions of existing file you can use

```java
Path p = Paths.get("/path/to/h2db.mv.db");
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(p, PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rwxrwx---"));
```

where `/path/to/h2db.mv.db` is an absolute or relative path to your file.

770, however, should not be used for database, database file is neither directory nor executable. Perhaps you meant 660, use `PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw----")` for it.

---

If you want to specify initial permissions using the Java code only, you need to create a new **empty** file with these permissions **before** creation of database:

```java
Path p = Paths.get("/path/to/h2db.mv.db");
Set<PosixFilePermission> perms = PosixFilePermissions.fromString("rw-rw----");
if (Files.notExists(p)) {
    Files.createFile(p, PosixFilePermissions.asFileAttribute(perms));
}
// Some permissions may be removed by umask during file creation, so
// they need to be set again
Files.setPosixFilePermissions(p, perms);
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:h2:/path/to/h2db");
```

---

It could be more reasonable to set the `umask` of the process to `0007` instead (from the shell code, for example, with `umask 0007`). With such `umask` new files will have permissions `660`, new executables and directories will have permissions `770`.

Comment: This I have done, my main point of asking the question is when we are creating this file at that time we can change the permission. The solution you provided is when the file was already created...